# SP 2010 adds extension to an image's file name when adding to library causing "double-extension"

Tags: 2010, picture-library, image-upload

As of last week, something changed in our SP2010 server that transformed all image paths to: `<filename>_<extension>.<extension>`.  I noticed some service packs were installed, but could not figure out how they may have inpacted.  Not only did it update all existing file names, when i add a new image, it creates the wrong file name.

Here is an image I just uploaded, with a simple Name:

[image: Name and title viewed from the Edit page]

Yet for some reason, this image can only be accessed by the following URL. Notice the double **jpg** at the end.

`http://intranet/comunicacao/news/PublishingImages/_w/01_rh_ricardo%20amorim_jpg.jpg`

Any help will be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the _w is the web version of the image and has the url format you show above.  If you keep clicking the images you should be able to view the original at the url you uploaded.

Maybe try typing in

/comunicacao/news/PublishingImages/01_rh_ricardo%20amorim.jpg

and see if it works.

Comment: That did it! thanks. What exactly are the _w, _t used for? Are they for internal use only, should not be used by web-parts?

Comment: Your webparts can use them.  _t is the thumbnail (usually max 150px) and the _w is the web version (usually max 640px).  I've used the _w version before in a picture rotator webpart I created to reduce the possiblity of someone uploading 20 5MB files into a picture rotator and that negatively affecting the end user's experience.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my post as well, I was using the URL in a webpart. In your case, how did you use the _w in the webpart, did you have to account for the double file extension?

Comment: I just used the EncodedAbsWebImgUrl field value.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.encodedabswebimgurl.aspx

Comment: Didn't know about that field, nice.  How do you use the _w with EncodedAbsWebImgUrl?

Comment: That field will give you the full _w url to the item.

Comment: Understand. The documentation was a bit light on details. Thanks again!